# How to suggest ComboBox values by searching

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm creating a windows application and I want to show combo box value by filtering from the user input value. There is a property called `AutoComplete` but I'm assigning values for `comboBox` items using an object. So I couldn't fill `AutoCompletedSource`. How can I assign my item list to it?

Comment: kindly upload your code so we can help out!

Comment: This is code for assigning values from object to comboBox is called "drTeam"

drTeams.Items.Add(obj.team.teamName);

Comment: @OshadhaPunchihewa use the edit button at the bottom of the post to add your code.

Comment: Can you post your code, it's quite tough for us to help you? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two main ways to get autocomplete on a combo box.  The first is to set the source to the comboBox.Items:

```
        comboBox1.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.Suggest;
        comboBox1.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.ListItems;
        comboBox1.Items.AddRange(new []{"Omg", "So Kewel"," I love it"});
```

The second is to set up a custom source.  In the second case the drop down arrow will reveal nothing but the autocomplete will show when you start typing.

```
        comboBox1.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.Suggest;
        comboBox1.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource;

        var list = new List<string>() {"Omg", "So Kewl", "I love it"};
        var collection = new AutoCompleteStringCollection();
        collection.AddRange(list.ToArray());

        comboBox1.AutoCompleteCustomSource = collection;
```